# How can I receive a variable back in my routes.js to load a different view?

Tags: react-native

I am using a switchNavigator to display either a show view or a view where the user can add more content. I want to send back a boolean variable just as a flag, I think I have that part just right but I don't know how to make it so that my code receives it and changes view.

This is in my `routes.js`

```
let hasItems = true;
const ItemsScreens = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Items: {
      screen: Items,
    },
    ItemsExist: {
      screen: ExistingItems,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'card',
    initialRouteName: hasItems ? 'ItemsExist' : 'Items',
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: getDrawerItemIcon('account-balance-wallet'),
      title: `Items`,
    },
  },
);
```

inside my `ExistingItems.js` I have a button that does:

```
<Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Items', {hasItems: false})}
          label={'Add Items'}
        />
```

My idea is to call the view again but send the false value in the variable to enter the actual adding items state but I have no idea how to make it actually receive the value. I tried doing an if like:

```
if(this.props.navigation.state.params.hasItems)
```

but that is undefined and crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [react navigation Authentication flows example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html), create one another screen `AuthLoadingScreen`, which checks the condition and according to condition navigate to your another screen. However, I also know that extra screen will not good for user UI but it will work around.

Answer (score 0):

Which property is seen as `undefined`?

Aren't you also controlling the wrong variable? the param you are passing is `hasBanks` but you are controlling `hasItems`